# How to have a cron job run a specific script every day to Query a new quote

Tags: php, time, cron, cron-task

I have a table with 1000 quotes stored, each with an auto incremented primary key ID. Each day at  6:00 AM I would like to run a script that queries a random ID number and returns the quote associated with that ID. I have never used a Cron Job before and when approaching it in Cpanel it does not exactly step you through how it is done. Is there a way to trigger a specific function with a cron job at a specific time each day?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**

Comment: the cron job is trivial, have you got a script to make the query etc?

Comment: Sidenote: I may have closed the question prematurely based on *"Is there a way to trigger a specific function"*. However, this does seem to be the case here, "how to run a cron job at a specific time". If I did do a bad close, then ping me and I'll reopen. However, do add extra information/detail to the question should it be the case.

Comment: if you have the script i'll writer the cron job command, but i ssuspect you dont have the script yet. you should ask a new question on that.